# Rate limiting on API using Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, rate-limiting

I have deployed multiple APIs on Kubernetes using GKE ingress, and want to enable Rate limiting on all deployed API,

I have tried Nginx ingress and it has option for rate limiting but i have to use GKE ingress because of it support global load balancing.

Also i have search for Istio and Ambassador which supports rate limiting ,

But i am new to envoy services, Can anybody suggest what option will be good for rate limiting for my multiple apis.

Comment: Provide more details so we can advice a solution based on them, not on our preferences.

Comment: @Crou , Simply i want rate limiting on my apis which i have deployed it on kubernetes and accessing it via GKE ingress https.